# Delphi REST client can't create event in Google Calendar - Parse Error

Tags: api, delphi, google-calendar-api, rest-client, parse-error

I realise that there's a duplicate question, but it wasn't answered, so I'm raising the question again with my own code that doesn't work.

I'm trying to send HTTP requests to the Google Calendar/v3 API using the REST client library components in DELPHI XE5 Update 2 (TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESToAuth2Autenticator, TRESTResponse).

Why doesn't the following work?  All I get is a Bad Request stating "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input". I have specified application/json in the Client and the Request, yet it is ignoring this and still sending as Form Encoded.

```
JB := TlkJSONObject.Create;
 JBStart := TlkJSONObject.Create;
 JBEnd := TlkJSONObject.Create;
 try
    JB.Add('Summary', 'Another Test');
    JBStart.Add('DateTime', '2016-02-09T17:00:00');
    JBStart.Add('TimeZone', 'Europe/London');
    JB.Add('Start', JBStart);
    JBEnd.Add('DateTime', '2016-02-09T18:00:00');
    JBEnd.Add('TimeZone', 'Europe/London');
    JB.Add('End', JBEnd);
    Event := TlkJSON.GenerateText(JB);
    finally
    FreeAndNil(JB);
    end;

 Client.BaseURL := 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + CalID + '/events?key=' + ClientInfo.APIKey;
 Client.ContentType := 'application/json;';

 Req.AddBody(Event, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
 Req.Method := rmPOST;
 Req.Execute;
```